# IPv6 Neighbour Table Overflow: Stop Router from caching multicast addresses

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

**TL;DR:** How do I prevent IPv6 neighbour solicitations from creating multicast entries in the neighbour cache?

---

I recently installed the somewhat obscure [Padavan RT-N56U](https://bitbucket.org/padavan/rt-n56u/src/master/) firmware (Linux 3.4.110) on my oldish Asus RT-N56U router in hopes of getting a more stable internet connection, and promptly ran into IPv6 configuration problems. My ISP supports stateless DHCPv6 using router advertisement, which works fine and dandy - my router gets all the goodies it should from DHCP, including DNS entries.

However, the ISP is casting out neighbour solicitation `icmp6` packages to multicast addresses in `ff02::1:`, which then clog up my neighbour table:

```
/home/root # ip route show cache table all | grep -c ff02
1681
```

This table cyclically gets to the point of overflowing:

```
Sep  8 16:53:39 kernel: net_ratelimit: 705 callbacks suppressed
Sep  8 16:53:39 kernel: ipv6: Neighbour table overflow
Sep  8 17:02:41 kernel: net_ratelimit: 83 callbacks suppressed
Sep  8 17:02:41 kernel: ipv6: Neighbour table overflow
Sep  8 17:03:41 kernel: net_ratelimit: 1762 callbacks suppressed
Sep  8 17:03:41 kernel: ipv6: Neighbour table overflow
```

And when I capture the TCP packets on my WAN port:

```
/home/root # tcpdump -i eth3 -v ip6
11:07:27.055286 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::ce4e:24ff:fe1c:3300 > ff02::1:ff5a:c: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has [redacted ipv6 GUA]
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): cc:4e:24:1c:33:00
11:07:27.055330 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::ce4e:24ff:fe1c:3300 > ff02::1:ff86:1d: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has [redacted ipv6 GUA]
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): cc:4e:24:1c:33:00
11:07:27.055348 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::ce4e:24ff:fe1c:3300 > ff02::1:ffa6:8015: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has [redacted ipv6 GUA]
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): cc:4e:24:1c:33:00
11:07:27.055376 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::ce4e:24ff:fe1c:3300 > ff02::1:ff5b:8: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has [redacted ipv6 GUA]
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): cc:4e:24:1c:33:00
```

I understand that I could change the aggressiveness of the garbage collection mechanism, but is there a way to simply not cache those multicast addresses? Might this be less-than-sensible default behaviour and fixed in more recent releases?

---

Edit: The [NDP specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-5.1) state that the neighbour cache is supposed to hold unicast information:

> A set of entries about individual neighbors to which traffic has been sent recently.  Entries are keyed on the neighbor's on-link unicast IP address […]

I suppose this is a bug, then. Will post back if I find out what component of the stack is at fault.